# Dynamically reading point coordinates from Spreadsheet in GeoGebra

Tags: coordinates, geogebra

I was using GeoGebra and I wanted to create a point whose co-ordinates are dynamically read off of a spreadsheet. The spreadsheet would have two columns for the values of x and y co-ordinates of this point, and this point would have to dynamically move from the first (x,y) value all the way through to the last one.

I tried using a slider to refer to the elements of the spreadsheet but am unable to do so. If this could be done, all I would have to do was create an animate button for the slider and that would be it. But I cannot figure out how to name the elements of the spreadsheet while incorporating the slider name as well.

If this idea cannot be implemented, is there another way of creating moving points in GeoGebra based on coordinate values created in an external file(which I was planning to copy to the spreadsheet)?

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that the command 'Record to Spreadsheet' allows me to record coordinate values of the point onto a spreadsheet. But isn't there a way to do the opposite of this?

Comment: I am currently using the Object[] command to refer to a spreadsheet element. For instance elements of column A could be referred to as Object["A"+a] where a is the value of a slider. As the slider changes I can access different values of the column A. Of course the slider has to an integer type. I was still wondering if there is a better way to achieve this result though.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah , there are two methods to do that one of them is using Object[] commend as you indicate in the comment ; the seconde method is creating a list follow these steps :

- select a column  for exemple  **A** by clicking in the top of column
- Right Click
- create
- list
- then you can access to any element of the list in commend line by type  for creating a point : `(element(list1,n),element(list2,n))`

  n is the slider

hope i help you